# Join 2 tables in Eloquent Laravel 5.2 - How to retrieve all data from both two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables
1.

```
Game Console
      -- console_id
      -- console_name
```

2.

```
 Game Labels
     -- game_label_id
     -- console_id (foreign key)
     -- title
     -- description 
     -- image
     -- created
```

GameConsole Model

```
namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GameConsole extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'console';
    protected $fillable = array('console_name', 'description', 'created');
    protected $primaryKey = 'console_id';

    public function labels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\GameLabel','console_id');
    }

}
```

GameLabel Model

```
namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GameLabel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'game_label';
    protected $fillable = array('game_label_id','console_id', 'title','description','image', 'release_date','status','created');
    protected $primaryKey = 'game_label_id';

    public function console()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\GameConsole','console_id');
    }
}
```

I write this query to get all game labels with console_name

```
GameLabel::with('console')->get();
```

But I am only getting records from game_label table, not from console table.

Can any body please tell me that what query I have to write to get all records?
Please don't suggest me about query builder joins. I don't want to use that.

Comment: you can do like : `$gameLabel = GameLabel::with('console')->get();` then `$gameConsoles = $gameLabel->console;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its under console key. I found the solution.
the console name was not getting in the view so get the console name in view like this

```
foreach($game_label as $getGameLabel){
    echo $getGameLabel->console->console_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       namespace App\Http\Models;

        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

        class GameLabel extends Model
        {
            /**
             * The attributes that are mass assignable.
             *
             * @var array
             */
            public $timestamps = false;
            protected $table = 'game_label';
            protected $fillable = array('game_label_id','console_id', 'title','description','image', 'release_date','status','created');
            protected $primaryKey = 'game_label_id';

            public function console()
            {
               return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\GameConsole', 'console_id', 'console_id');
           }
}
```

in belongs to first console_id represent Game Console table id and and second  console_id represent game_label table console_id

now in controller

```
GameLabel::with('console')->get();
```

i think all data will be availbale in array under console key

Comment: Yes, its under console key. I found the solution.